# Susy Columns - Stacking Mobile

Tags: html, css, sass, susy

Ok, I'm new to Susy and I'm trying to do something that is probably very easy. On a large display I have two columns side-by-side |A|B|. When I shrink the browser down to a mobile size it stacks the columns A over B.

How would I make B stack over A? I have looked all over the place and I can't seem to find the mother load of layouts. I can read documentation all day long, but, I am a visual person. Is there a place where I can download some sample Susy grids to just mess with the settings to learn with?

I realize this is a very novice post, but, I have to start somewhere.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much Mohit! I am new to GitHub as well so cloning people's work didn't register in my mind like it should have.

Answer (score 0):

**The simplest option is to change the source order of your elements in HTML:**

```
<div class="b">column B</div>
<div class="a">column A</div>
```

If `b` comes first in the markup, it will automatically stack on top in the browser. You can still use Susy to arrange them horizontally in either order:

```
.a {
  @include span(8 of 12);
}

.b {
  @include span(last 4 of 12);
}
```

I don't know your layout, so I'm just making up numbers there. The `last` keyword will push `b` to the right, so `a` can fill in on the left.

**Your other option involves CSS flexbox:**

[Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) allows you to stack elements in any order, vertically or horizontally. If you want to go that direction, you should read something like this [CSS Tricks tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Susy and flexbox work great together, but you have to use the susy functions instead of the mixins. You can apply Susy functions anywhere flexbox expects a width, for example:

```
.b {
  flex-basis: span(4 of 12);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Miriam. I knew it had to be something simple. :)